# Random scroll behavour on gestureDetector onScroll() method

Tags: android, gesturedetector

I am implementing a scrolling panel in a app where user scroll the hidden container from top like as of Android's status bar notification panel.When i scroll top to bottom it works fine but when i scroll from bottom to top the `MotionEvent e2` gives random value. Here's what i have done:

My touch listener :

```
upSlide.setOnTouchListener(bottomTouchListener);
```

GestureDetector:

```
GestureDetector bottomGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(
        context, new BottomTouchGestureListener());

//touch listener
OnTouchListener bottomTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                animateView(sliderView.getTop(), -screenHeight);
            return true;
        }
        return bottomGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }
};
```

The GestureDetector:

```
class BottomTouchGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        if (e2.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    //left right swipe
                } else {
                    //top down swipe
                    slideOffset = Math.abs((int) diffY);
                    Log.e(TAG, "onScroll -->" + e2.getY() + "");
                    invalidate();
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
    }
}
```

And my log output is:

```
onScroll --> 40.83081
onScroll --> 1855.7668
onScroll --> 71.79602
onScroll --> 1843.0444
onScroll --> 50.157593
onScroll --> 1815.4504
onScroll --> 45.553223
onScroll --> 1778.2007
onScroll --> 48.40674
onScroll --> 1751.7765
onScroll --> 44.186157
onScroll --> 1715.3464
onScroll --> 44.40625
onScroll --> 1677.5885
onScroll --> 35.96411
onScroll --> 1624.1068
onScroll --> 22.843506
onScroll --> 1544.1412
onScroll --> 12.907837
onScroll --> 1441.6538
onScroll --> -5.8792725
onScroll --> 1300.1215
onScroll --> -36.662354
onScroll --> 1085.7295
onScroll --> -61.72827
onScroll --> 818.67615
onScroll --> -69.63501
onScroll --> 544.83466
```

If you notice the value for touch event `MotionEvent e2`are fluctuating onScroll so my view is also flickering. I dont understand the behaviour. Can someone explain why `motionEvent e2` is that random and solution for this???
It is working when i scroll from top to bottom but not while i scroll from bottom to top.

Comment: Why You didn't use `distanceX` and `distanceY` parameters of `onScroll()`?

Comment: @AndriyOmelchenko distanceX and distanceY are also giving similar random value and also distanceX and distanceY gives total scroll in X and Y doesnot reset value on direction change.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you hide the status bar (or any other view in the vertical structure), the vertical scroll coordinates are affected.

If you look at the `onScroll` docs, it says that `distanceY` is the delta between now and the last time `onScroll` was called. The last time `onScroll` was called in your case was before the status bar disappeared.

So the behavior is not "random" as you suggest, but rather a continuous toggle.